# How to dynamically construct query to filter the results in Spring JPA?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've a scenario where I have to filter the results based on the filter options provided by the user.

Below is the Model class:

```
class Site{  int price;  int length; int someProp;}
```

I've a JSP page which has filters like minPrice, maxPrice, minLength, maxLength, minSomeProp, maxSomeProp, etc.. All of these are optional. User can filter the Sites using these options.

I want to dynamically create query based on the passed filters. If all the filters are passed then my query looks like

```
findByPriceLessThanAndPriceGreaterThanAndLengthLessThanAndLengthGreaterThanAndLessThanSomePropAndGreaterThanSomeProp(param1, param2,param3, param4, param5, param6);
```

Is there any easy way to construct the query dynamically just using the passed filters?

Comment: Do you really need this syntax? Use HQL or CriteriaQuery instead

Answer (score 4):

You can create dynamic queries using [Specifications](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications). Take a look at this [great specification related lib](https://github.com/tkaczmarzyk/specification-arg-resolver) too.